# Having issues with simple VB script

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ssis, etl, script-task

I am having issues running the following VB script to create a new directory in my SSIS package. It should create the following new path D:\customers\documents\orders\20171205.

```vb
Public Sub Main()
    'set dir path
    Dts.Variables("var_DirPath").Value = 
        "D:\customers\documents\orders\" + Date.Today.Year.ToString + 
        Date.Today.Month.ToString + Date.Today.Day.ToString
    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

The ReadWriteVariables of the script task editor is configured to User:var_DirPath. The value of the variable is “D:\customers\documents\orders\"

The file task is configured for

```
UseDirector/Exists = True
Operation = Create directory
IsSourcePathAvailable = True
Source variable = User:var_DirPath
```

It resolves in the package during debugging, but I do not know why this simple script does not work.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Comment: Something seems fishy. The code you provided _should_ work, if not as nicely as @jmcihinney's suggestion.  For me it sets the var to "D:\customers\documents\orders\2017125". Can you alter your path or something to prove this code is running?

Comment: I think that using Variable with expression is more simpler than using Script task

Comment: @DavidF i provided some suggestions in  my answer, but please clarify what did you mean by `but I do not know why this simple script does not work.` ... *How it is not working? Are you receiving an Error message or what?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Some Suggestions

You have to make sure that the variable name is typed correctly, because the name is case sensitive. Also you can use `Date.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")` instead of concatenating the date parts.

```vb
Public Sub Main()
    'set dir path
    Dts.Variables("var_DirPath").Value = 
    "D:\customers\documents\orders\" & Date.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd")
    Dts.TaskResult = ScriptResults.Success
End Sub
```

**Also make sure to set the File System Task `Delay Validation` property to `True`**

## Simpler Solution - Using Expression

By the way you can achieve this using a expressions, Just go to the variable list, click on the variable `var_DirPath`, press F4 to show the properties Tab, Set `Evaluate as expression` property to `True`, click on the `Expression` property and use the following expression:

```
 "D:\\customers\\documents\\orders\\" + (DT_STR, 4, 1252) DATEPART("yyyy" , GETDATE()) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("MM" , GETDATE()), 2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("dd" , GETDATE()), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you wouldn't see any date subfolder but that code has other issues.  For instance, January 11 and November 1 would produce the same folder name for the same year.  Try this:

```
Dts.Variables("var_DirPath").Value = String.Format("D:\customers\documents\orders\{0:yyyyMMdd}", Date.Now)
```

That is better than concatenation and the format ensures unique folder names for all dates.